# Large Ajax Application Design Patterns

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm currently pretty decent at coding C# web applications in ASP.NET MVC 3, PHP + Cake, and Java Spring. Working with these three, I feel comfortable about creating Layered Data, Domain, Service, and Presentation applications. I can organize them well.

But with the need for highly responsive AJAX. I really feel uncomfortable for using jQuery to hook every single little model postback to the controller.

Are there any MVC (Controller + View + View Model + JavaScript) Design Patterns? I've recently started reading about Knockout JS and Backbone.js but don't really seem to understand the "architecture" big words and the benefits they bring let alone healthy design patterns.

Are there any good tutorials or examples out there that demonstrate an advanced JavaScript Application like Google Docs/Calendar/Mail or things like Compilr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few MVC implementations in javascript.

Frankly, the more ajax development is done, the more obvious it becomes that not only do you need server side templating, models, views, controllers, etc, you also need something like this on the javascript side, especially when a lot of dom manipulation is concerned.

The following is a list of popular frameworks:
http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

However, please note that a lot of these have progressed toward the node.js model (in which both client side and server side(s) use javascript syntax.

When developing with C# or asp.net, etc, you're better off to plan that portion of the architecture as a service layer. Then you push a lot of the templating responsibility to static files and javascript, which is definitely where you wanna be when you're scaling up.

Then again, you're also going to run into a lot of ideological questions along the way that you will simply have to decide for yourself.

Comment: This may show my ignorance, but when you say 'push templating responsibility to static files and javascript', what is the difference from say a stock MVC/Razor setup?

Comment: MVC is simply a design pattern and can be implemented anywhere. So, you can be writing views on the server side that are tightly coupled with dynamic data, and therefore you can't really cache it. Once a project becomes javascripty enough, you end up doing so much dom manipulation that you have lots of strings like "<li>"+someVar+"</li>" all over your code. this is when you'll see the value in having a static client side mvc.

Comment: Right, thanks. I will have to investigate - I have always been doing the stock web server/client template/js approach.

Comment: Also, I recently went the route of using node js, and you really have a ton more flexibility for doing large scale javascript applications. checkout backbone.js, geddy, require.js... tons of value there

Answer (score 2):

If you are in to serious JS development, there are many concerns other than MVC you need to think about.

- structuring the solution
- creating a module hierarchy
- Dependency management of JS files
- Event based messaging for decoupled communication
- Routing, book-marking and embeddable components
- Unit testing
- Localization
- Document generation
- JS optimizations and obfuscation

After couple of complex JS projects, I wanted to share my experience in building complex applications so created BoilerplateJS. BoilerplateJS is a reference architecture for large scale development with concerns such as above are addressed.

http://boilerplatejs.org/

BoilerplateJS lets you to structure your complex product suite in to product-modules and UI components. There are several samples implemented to follow in the reference architecture code base.